# Move xml element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <i xmlns="http://stuff.com" >
        <v>
            <iNumber>0118</iNumber>
            <s>1</s>
            <a>24</a>
            <p>2175</p>
            <p>2175</p>
            <p>4534</p>
        </v>
    </i>
```

But I need the export to look like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <i xmlns="http://stuff.com" >
        <v>
            <iNumber>0118</iNumber>
            <s>1</s>
            <a>24</a>
            <p>2175</p>
        </v>
        <v>
            <iNumber>0118</iNumber>
            <s>1</s>
            <a>24</a>
            <p>2175</p>
        </v>
            <iNumber>0118</iNumber>
            <s>1</s>
            <a>24</a>
            <p>4534</p>
        </v>
    </i>
```

I am new to xslt so I would like some help with transforming this xml please

Here's my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:stuff="http://stuff.com" exclude-result-prefixes="stuff">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="stuff:v">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::stuff:v/stuff:p"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've updated my question to show my attempt

Comment: Do you have a specific question or difficulty? Or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you?

Comment: I would like some some help writing it

Comment: Start writing, we''ll help you when you get stuck.

Comment: I updated my question with my attempt. Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:stuff="http://stuff.com" exclude-result-prefixes="stuff">

    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stuff:v">
        <xsl:for-each select="stuff:p">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::stuff:v" mode="copying">
                <xsl:with-param name="pId" select="generate-id()" /> 
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stuff:v" mode="copying">
        <xsl:param name="pId" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="pId" select="$pId" /> 
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stuff:p">
        <xsl:param name="pId"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = $pId">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some explanation. The first template matching `node()|@*` just copies things by default.

The second template matching `stuff:v` will take over when a stuff:v element is encountered. It will iterate over all stuff:p elements in it, and for each of them applies matching templates to its stuff:v ancestor. However, it enters a mode I named "copying" and calls the templates with a parameter `pId` which is the id of the p element. Each element in XML has some implicit id that uniquely identifies it.

This way we end up in the next template, which also matches `stuff:v` but only in mode "copying". It accepts a pId parameter, copies the v element and then applies templates to all its attributes and child nodes, no longer with the "copying" mode **but with the pId parameter**. That last part is crucial.

The final template matches `stuff:p` but will only copy it if the id of that element is the same as the one given in the pId parameter.

So basically, we get to stuff:v, go through each stuff:p in it, for each of them it goes to stuff:v again in a different mode to match another template (otherwise it would recurse infinitely), and from there copy everything but for stuff:p elements require that they match a parameter passed into the template.

Comment: Thank you so much for the anser @G_H it works great but the only thing is that it does not copy the `stuff:iNumber`. It copies everything else, `stuff:s`, `stuff:a`, `stuff:p`

Comment: @1122335 That's odd, it copies the iNumber element just fine in my test. Are there multiple namespaces in the XML you're using for testing? Which XSLT processor is this?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out, thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stuff="http://stuff.com" 
exclude-result-prefixes="stuff">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/stuff:i">
    <i xmlns="http://stuff.com">
        <xsl:for-each select="stuff:v/stuff:p">
            <v>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::stuff:p)]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </v>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </i>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```